# comparing cell of strings with different size in matlab

Tags: matlab

i want to compare [1*232] cells of strings containing individual words from text document with [1*23]  cells that contain individual sentences from the same text, can any one help me how to program it in Matlab?
for example:
"pollution" and "trees" are two words in separate cells
and following are the two sentences in separate cells:
1. trees reduce pollution.
2. trees prevent floods.

what i want to do is put 0 or 1 after comparing pollution and trees with both the sentences or in my case "n" sentences and put 1's and 0's in the form of matrices.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `strfind`, example: `document={'trees reduce pollution','trees prevent floods'};index=strfind(document,'pollution');found=cellfun(@(x)(~isempty(x)),index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `cellfun` and `strfind`. Here is a try:

```
Sentences = {'trees reduce pollution' ; ... 
    'trees prevent floods' ; ...
    'pollution is bad' ; ...
    'flood is worse'};

Words = {'trees', 'pollution', 'bad'};

Out = NaN(numel(Sentences), numel(Words));

for i = 1:numel(Words)
    Out(:,i) = cellfun(@(x) numel(strfind(x, Words{i})), Sentences);
end
```

And `Out` contains:

```
Out =

     1     1     0
     1     0     0
     0     1     1
     0     0     0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a ton, this logic worked for me absolutely fine.cheers

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment. Don't hesitate to mark this question as "solved".